# Is it possible to download a file using PrimeFaces RemoteCommand?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a page with a table that has optional columns the user can hide and show.
When the user chooses to download the content of the table via a link at the bottom of the table, I want to send them the content of the currently displayed columns.

In order to do that I need to use a remote command since a regular commandLink will not accept js parameters to tell the server which columns are currently being displayed.

My problem is that the file is not being downloaded. When I debug, I get to my sever method and go through the whole process completely, when I return to the browser I see the content of the file in the network tab in Chrome, but the file is not being downloaded and instead my page is being refreshed. If I put return false after I invoke the command, I see the file in the network tab in Chrome, and the page does not refresh but nothing happens.
I tried to use the onSuccess or onComplete events, but those do not seem to work as I expect.

Can this be done using JSF or will I have to write a servlet for this?

Here is my code:
The link

```
<h:commandLink value="Download data" onclick="invokeDownload();return false;" />
```

The invoke js method:

```
var invokeDownload = function() {
        var columnLabels = getVisibleColumns().toString();
        downloadTableData([{ "name": "columnLabels", "value": columnLabels     }]);
    }
```

The remote command:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="downloadTableData" action="#{myBean.dataTable.download()}" process="@this"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to use a remoteCommand here? I expect this would be a lot easier with a servlet.

Comment: What about `p:fileDownload`? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

Comment: @Xtreme, I believe that p:fileDownload is for existing files. Is there a way to send parameters to the backing method to construct the file with the relevant data?

Comment: @Syren, the reason is that it will not be consistent with how we usually download tables which are not configurable. If nothing else works I will have to go the servlet route, but that will make the code harder to maintain, especially for new people joining our team.

Comment: Talbam, indeed, filedownload invokes a getter method. Usually is not a good idea to implement business logic in a getter, but I would consider this as an exception. There are ways to send parameters to the bean before the download but it would be interesting to know how you show/hide the columns. In fact, if you do it at client side you won't be able to send them when you invoke the method. You need to maintain the table state in your bean.

Comment: I dont really see the big difference between configurable data and fixed data. Since you dont have an `oncomplete` handler in the `remoteCommand` the problem may be in the `dataTable.download()` method. Care to post that one?

Comment: Files cannot Ajaxically be downloaded. Then I skipped the question :)

Comment: @Tiny "Ajaxically"

Answer (score 5):

No. The `<p:remoteCommand>` fires an ajax request. You can however not download files with ajax. Ajax is executed by JavaScript code, which has for obvious security reasons no facilities to force a *Save As* dialog with some data held in some JavaScript variable.

Just fire a synchronous request. You can let JS populate hidden input fields having the same names as the request parameters you're attempting to pass through.

```
<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" />
<input type="hidden" id="value" name="value" />
<h:commandLink value="Download data" 
    onclick="populateDownloadData()"
    action="#{myBean.dataTable.download()}" />
```

```
function populateDownloadData() {
    var columnLabels = getVisibleColumns().toString();
    document.getElementById("name").value = "columnLabels";
    document.getElementById("value").value = columnLabels;
}
```

Those params are by the way somewhat strange. Perhaps you're confused by `<p:remoteCommand>` examples. I'd just have used a single request parameter with name `columnLabels`.

```
<input type="hidden" id="columnLabels" name="columnLabels" />
<h:commandLink value="Download data" 
    onclick="populateDownloadData()"
    action="#{myBean.dataTable.download()}" />
```

```
function populateDownloadData() {
    var columnLabels = getVisibleColumns().toString();
    document.getElementById("columnLabels").value = columnLabels;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `dataExporter` tag form Primefaces, which is meant to download the content of displayed table: [Primefaces dataExporter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml)

Comment: The table is not a PrimeFaces table, and even if it was, the data exporter does not give enough flexibility for me to download the data in the required format.

Comment: @Talbam, the dataExporter is customizable and extendable. It supports 4 formats by default, and it is not particularly challenging to add support for additional formats. If you can find a simpler solution, fantastic, please post an answer, but the dataExporter is perfectly capable of what you're asking for.

Comment: The table I have on the page is not a PrimeFaces table, and according to the dataExporter code, such tables are not supported: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.1.RC1/org/primefaces/component/export/DataExporter.java/